# Sed/Awk deleting selective lines

Tags: unix, awk, sed, line

This may be a simple question, but I am struggling to find a solution, could anyone provide a simple UNIX sed or awk command to delete every 3rd and 4th line of a file starting from say the 5th line.

Comment: might help to show some sample input and your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GNU sed, you can use the `FIRST~STEP` address format, eg.

```
sed -e '6~3 d' -e '8~4 d' file
```

deletes the 6th line, then every 3rd, and deletes the 8th line, then every 4th.

Comment: Cheers found this, but don't have GNU sed, should of stated that!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've understood the requirements, you can use `awk` as follows:

```
pax$ echo '1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15' | awk '{if (((NR - 5) % 4 < 2) || (NR < 5)) {print}}'
1
2
3
4
5
6
9
10
13
14
```

As you can see, this uses `NR` (the line number) to decide whether or not to print the line.

Starting from line 5, it prints two then skips two, ad infinitum. Below 5, it prints everything.

If I've misunderstood exactly *which* lines you want skipped, the theory is still sound, you just have to adjust the `if` statement.

Comment: oh, that LISP style:) This is equivalent to `awk '(NR - 5) % 4 < 2 || NR < 5'`

Answer (score 2):

an awk solution, where you pass your numbers as parameters:

```
awk -v start=5 -v d1=3 -v d2=4 '
    {n = NR - start}
    n > 0 && (n % d1 == 0 || n % d2 == 0) {next} 
    1
'
```

This skips lines 8, 11, 14, ... and 9, 13, 17, ...

Answer (score 0):

How about Perl?

```
perl -pi -e 'print if $. < 5 or 1 == $. % 4 or 2 = $. % 4' your_file
```